# how to get the value found, instead of replacing? using preg_replace php

Tags: php, web

how to get the value found, instead of replacing?

```
echo $response=$htmlParserA->find("/tbody/tr/td",5)->plaintext."<br>";
$str=preg_replace("/[0-9][0-9][0-9]/","",$response);
echo $str;
```

Response:
Before HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
After HTTP/1.1 Moved Permanently

how to get 301?

ANSWER:

```
$str=preg_match("/[0-9][0-9][0-9]/",$response,$asd); 
echo $asd[0];
```

Comment: preg_match instead of preg_replace

Comment: @developerwjk, Not.  preg_match return  true||false.

Comment: preg_grep  then: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php

Comment: @developerwjk
I read it all! it requires an array. and I have a string. you know php at all?

Comment: I knew I was right the first time: preg_match. Yes, it returns true/false, but you pass in an array which it fills with the matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

preg_match will do what you want:

```
$input = "HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently";
$matches = array();
$found = preg_match("/\d{3}/", $input, $matches);
if($found)
{
    echo "Code = " . $matches[0];
}
```

If desired, you could make the pattern more strict:

```
$found = preg_match("/HTTP\/1\.1\s(\d{3})/", $input, $matches);
if($found)
{
    echo "Code = " . $matches[1];
}
```

Comment: I fixed your code more compact
$str=preg_match("/[0-9][0-9][0-9]/",$response,$asd);
      echo $asd[0];